# How do i emit to only targeted user?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My goal is to send a live notification to another user.

1. User A browse, and found User B
2. User A clicks Add friend
3. User B Received The notification

I have used both `io` and `socket` to emit, what happened are

1. io case, is that it emits to all the connected user.
2. socket case, is that it emits to itself.

if you see the code below, I use `socket.request.user` , I got that from using passport.socketio library, just want to clarify.

Codes

Serverside

```
io.on('connection', function() {
   socket.on('friendsRequest', function(data) {
      var userId = data;

      User.update(
        {
          _id: userId,
          'friendsRequested.requestee': { $ne: socket.request.user._id}
        },
        {
          $push: { friendsRequested: { requestee: socket.request.user._id } },
        }, function(err, count) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          console.log("Successful");
          socket.emit('friendsRequest', socket.request.user);
        });
      });

});
```

Client-Side

```
$(document).on('click', "#addFriend", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var userId = $('#userId').val(); // Getting the userId from the input hidden (This is User B _id from mongoDB)
  $('#addFriend').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success') // Change the button to green color
  .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Added').attr('id', 'addFriend');
  socket.emit('friendsRequest', userId); // Emit the userId back to the server.
});

socket.on('friendsRequest', function(data) { // if successful

  var totalRequests = parseInt($('#totalRequests').html()); // Get the current total friendsRequest
  totalRequests += 1; // Increment by 1
  $('#totalRequests').html(totalRequests); // Change it to the current totalRequest
  $('#friendsRequested').append('<li>' + data._id + '</li>');
});
```

Again, let say User A clicks Add Friend button on User B page, how do only User B gets the notification but not User A?

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a minimalistic but runable example based on sockets only:

```
var net = require('net');
var users = [];    // sockets are stored here

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    users.push(socket);                      // store socket to var users
    socket.write('you are connected\n');     // message to current socket
    for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i] == socket) {
            continue;                        // skip current socket
        }
        users[i].write('new user joined\n'); // send to all other sockets
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

You have to store each socket to be able to use each socket individually.

The example above shows how to avoid one certain socket but it is a similar procedure if you want to use only one certain socket.

As malix pointed out, you need add an information to be able to identify that certain socket later, e.g. the email address or a user id.

Comment: Because my problem is more towards, how do i send a live notification to other user other than myself.

Comment: You need to store the socket together with something to identify it for later use. Then you can refer to that socket. e.g. if you want to send a message only to the first connected user, then use  ```users[0].write('hello first user\n')```

Comment: If it is good to use a database or an array, to use a for-loop or not... Totally up to your application and the use case.  I'm pretty sure there are good working production systems which also use an array and a for-loop :)

Comment: I tried to follow your code, but with my logic. I keep getting this error

Comment: `sockets[userId].emit("friendsRequest", socket.request.user); TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined`

Comment: what is the different between emit and write?

Comment: write is the default way to send data to a socket when using the net module: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback

Comment: emit is - when used by the socket.io module - emits an event to all connected client

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jackMoscovi/a0facecbe47f7db912c4 is there any problem with with?

Answer (score 0):

Each socket is identified by a id, knowning it you can emit only to this socket like this:

```
io.sockets.connected[id].emit('friendsRequest', data);
```

So you could set the userId as property for each socket sending it from client, for example (server side):

```
socket.on('setuserid, function(data){
    socket.userid=data;
})
```

Or using passport.socketio maybe you can do:

```
socket.on('setuserid, function(){
    socket.userid=socket.request.user._id;
})
```

And when send a friend request, loop through the sockets connected (server side):

```
 socket.on('friendsRequest', function(data) {
  var userId = data;

  User.update(
    {
      _id: userId,
      'friendsRequested.requestee': { $ne: socket.request.user._id}
    },
    {
      $push: { friendsRequested: { requestee: socket.request.user._id } },
    }, function(err, count) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      console.log("Successful");

       for (s in io.sockets.connected) {

         if (userId==io.sockets.connected[s].userid) {

          io.sockets.connected[s].emit('friendsRequest', socket.request.user);
          break;

        };
      }

    });
  });
```

Comment: What if i use socket.to(socketId) ? whats the difference?

Comment: I never had seen that, but if work there is not difference

Answer (score -1):

We use [feathers](http://feathersjs.com) on top of Express and store the socket by email :

```
var app = feathers(); // same as app = express();
app.sockets = {};

//...

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // feathers puts the current user on the socket object for you, but you can roll your own
  // in that case, replace email with some other unique user data
  var email = socket.feathers.user.email; 
  if (email) {
    app.sockets[email] = socket;
  }
```

> notice that `socket` comes from arguments[0] of `io.on('connection')`

then you can target any email..

```
//find the user's socket and emit to it...
var target = app.sockets[toEmail];
target && target.emit('friendsRequest', {
        message: 'whatever',
        broadcast: false
      });
```

BTW, you don't **need** *feathers* for this... If you don't, just associate some unique user data with the socket on 'connection' and lookup the socket when you want to send something to that user only...

Comment: what is app.sockets? can you explain what it is actually?

Comment: sorry, app comes from express() and app.sockets is just a normal object `app.sockets = {};`